# PowerShell 2.0 Disk Space check

Tags: powershell

Below is the code for checking the disk space:

```
$disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName WDSMS01 -Namespace root\cimv2 -Query "Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3"

$disks.DeviceID
$dsql01 = @()

foreach($db in $disks)
{
    $dsql = New-Object PSObject
    $dsql | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive Name" -value $db.DeviceID
    $dsql | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Total Space(GB)" -value ($db.Size/1GB)
    $dsql | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Free Space(GB)" -value ($db.FreeSpace/1GB)
    $dsql01 += $dsql
}

$dsql01
```

Is it possible to limit the decimals by 2 digits? Also, add another column that computes free space in % format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends a bit on what exactly you need. You can use `[Math]::Round` to round off everything after two digits:

```
[Math]::Round($db.Size/1GB, 2)
```

but that can leave you with numbers that have less than two digits if they are followed by zeroes, e.g. `14.6` which doesn't look as nice in a table.

The other option is to format the numbers:

```
($db.Size/1GB).ToString('0.00')
```

which will always use the same number of decimal digits, *but* results in a string, so performing further calculations can be hindered by that.

As for your second question, that's actually trivial, just add another `Add-Member` call:

```
$dsql | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Free Space (%)' (100*$db.FreeSpace/$db.Size)
```

Also you can (in PowerShell v2) put all those in a single `New-Object` call:

```
$dsql = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    'Drive Name' = $db.DeviceID
    'Total Space (GB)' = $db.Size / 1GB
    'Free Space (GB)' = $db.FreeSpace / 1GB
    'Free Space (%)' = 100 * $db.FreeSpace / $db.Size
}
```

And while we're at it, `foreach` loops are so not PowerShell-y. Let's rewrite that with a pipeline:

```
$disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName WDSMS01 -Namespace root\cimv2 -Query "Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3"
$disks.DeviceID
$dsql01 = $disks | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Drive Name' = $_.DeviceID
        'Total Space (GB)' = $_.Size / 1GB
        'Free Space (GB)' = $_.FreeSpace / 1GB
        'Free Space (%)' = 100 * $_.FreeSpace / $_.Size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use formatter example:

```
PS>"{0:N2}" -f (11531055554 /1GB)
10,74
```

to get percent :

```
 $pfree=$dsql.free *100 /$dsql.total
 $dsql| Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "pFree" -value $pfree
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`-value ("{0:0.00}" -f ($db.Size/1GB))`

`-value ("{0:0.00}" -f ($db.FreeSpace/1GB))`